# How Change magento custom message

Tags: magento

i'm new to magento. I just want to find out which files can I go to if I want to change the magento default messages, like "Your password has been updated"

I tried to look at the magento forum but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Check the locale directory:

```
app/locale/en_US/*.csv
```

this directory will contain messages and their translations into different languages, each language/locale having it's own directory:

```
app/locale/en_GB/*.csv
app/locale/fr_FR/*.csv
```

Remember to refresh the magento cache once you've updated any of the translations / messages.